# Pandas / Resample with Interpolate produces NaN for the numeric column

Tags: pandas

I have one DataFrame made of 2 series

```
today = pd.to_datetime("today")
s1= pd.Series(pd.date_range(today, periods=6, freq='D'))
s2=pd.Series(range(6))
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(date=s1, data=s2))
df.set_index('date',inplace=True)
```

Which gives :

[image]

I try to resample the time with interpolation :

```
df.resample("12h").interpolate()
```

But I got Nan for the data column (I was expecting a **0.5 step** serie for this column)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply an operation between `resample` and `interpolate` to align source and target indexes, something like `first` will do the job as we won't have multiple values for the same datetime since we're upsampling (`last`, `mean` etc will have the same effect):

```
df.resample("12h").first().interpolate()
```

Comment: Indeed it works. What I don't get is that is [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72826357/pandas-i-cant-format-the-data-after-resample-interpolate/72826389#72826389), it was not a necessity to use this first function