# Pandas / I can't format the data after Resample.Interpolate

Tags: python, pandas

I have these data coming from a csv file

[image]

I did an interpolate with a 5 min period

```
ecoData = ecoData.resample('5min').interpolate()
ecoData.head()
```

Here is the result

[image]

Then I would like to keep only 2 digits so I did a test on the first column :

```
ecoData["1/31/2019"].map('{:.2f}'.format)
ecoData.head()
```

But nothing has changed as a result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you save the result?

```
ecoData["1/31/2019"] = ecoData["1/31/2019"].map('{:.2f}'.format)
ecoData.head()
```

Comment: My mistake !!! Indeed ecodata.head() was displaying the previous version. I was struggling like a creazy for that

Comment: Yes, it happens sometimes (xD). Could you validate my answer please?